# Export specific table columns to Excel

Tags: php, sql, database, excel

I'm trying to export specific column data (i.e., Ticket #, Company/Customer Name, Issue Subject, Date Closed) from my SQL DB table to Excel (.xls), I have the code written but it's exporting my entire Database table. (See code Below)

Specific column data that needs to be exported:

- ticketID
- name
- company
- subject
- closed

Also is there any way to add a function that only exports a specific range (i.e., Date range from October 1, 2012 to October 31, 2012)?

`<?PHP

//EDIT YOUR MySQL Connection Info:
$DB_Server = "localhost";        //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "root";                 //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "";                //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "my_databse";                //your MySQL Database Name
$DB_TBLName = "my_table";                //your MySQL Table Name

//$DB_TBLName,  $DB_DBName, may also be commented out & passed to the browser
//as parameters in a query string, so that this code may be easily reused for
//any MySQL table or any MySQL database on your server

//DEFINE SQL QUERY:
//edit this to suit your needs
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";

//Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp
//for when file was generated:
//set $Use_Titel = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
$Use_Title = 1;
//define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
$now_date = DATE('m-d-Y H:i');
//define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
$title = "Dump For Table $DB_TBLName from Database $DB_DBName on $now_date";
/*

Leave the connection info below as it is:
just edit the above.

(Editing of code past this point recommended only for advanced users.)
*/
//create MySQL connection
$Connect = @MYSQL_CONNECT($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
     or DIE("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR() . "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//select database
$Db = @MYSQL_SELECT_DB($DB_DBName, $Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't select database:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//execute query
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($sql,$Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());

//if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
//if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1))
{
     $file_type = "msword";
     $file_ending = "doc";
}ELSE {
     $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
     $file_ending = "xls";
}
//header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
HEADER("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MDT_DB_$now_date.$file_ending");
HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
HEADER("Expires: 0");

/*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */

IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\n"; //new line character

     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
         //define field names
         $field_name = MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$j);
         //will show name of fields
         $schema_insert .= "$field_name:\t";
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j])) {
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                 }
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "") {
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                 }
             ELSE {
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                 }
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         //end of each mysql row
         //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row
         PRINT "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
     }
}ELSE{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

     //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
     FOR ($i = 0; $i < MYSQL_NUM_FIELDS($result); $i++)
     {
         ECHO MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$i) . "\t";
     }
     PRINT("\n");
     //end of printing column names

     //start while loop to get data
     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j]))
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "")
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
             ELSE
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         //following fix suggested by Josue (thanks, Josue!)
         //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain \n or \r
         //these two characters are now replaced with a space
         $schema_insert = PREG_REPLACE("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         PRINT "\n";
     }
}

?>`

Comment: Change the SQL and define what field you need from database. Is there any date field or timestamp in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the SQL:

```
//DEFINE SQL QUERY:
//edit this to suit your needs
$sql = "Select ticketID, name, company, subject, closed  from $DB_TBLName";
```

Comment: That did it! You're the man now dog!!

Now is there anyway that I can sort by or ORDER BY the 'closed' date before it exports the data?

Comment: Or even better to add a specific date range to export?

Comment: yes you can sort it by closed ASC or desc, just change the sql like this: $sql = "Select ticketID, name, company, subject, closed  from $DB_TBLName ORDER BY closed ASC";

Comment: For a specific date range, $sql = "Select ticketID, name, company, subject, closed  from $DB_TBLName WHERE closed > '2012-01-22' AND closed < '2012-10-30'";

Comment: hmm... well that seemed to work but I'm seeing a bunch of 'NULL' entries, which I don't need in there. How can I sort by Date (i.e. 10/30, 10/29, 10/28, etc)? Right now it's sorting by my oldest closed date.

Comment: change the sort order to DESC instead of ASC and to get rid of NULL values add name != NULL in where clause

Comment: I'm an idiot.. I completely disregarded your first sentence "you can sort it by closed ASC or desc" I got it working now with 'desc'.

Now is there any way to query a specific date range?

Comment: For a specific date range, $sql = "Select ticketID, name, company, subject, closed from $DB_TBLName WHERE closed > '2012-01-22' AND closed < '2012-10-30'"